# Position of Combination

Tags: combinatorics

Someone picks an arbitrary number of integers between 1 and N without replacement. These numbers are then sorted in ascending order. Thus, the result could be [2, 3, 4], but not [3, 2, 4]. In total, there are $2^N - 1$ unique sequences. E.g. if N = 3, the sequences are [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3].

Is there a function that tells me at which position in the vector of potential outcomes a sequence is located, without computing the vector first? Using the example of N = 3: the sequence [2, 3] corresponds to position 6.

I am also looking for a function that handles the computation vice versa, deriving the sequence given N and the position.

I guess that this is a common question to which there is a well established solution. However, I did not find it.

Feel free to use a programming language (preferably R or C++) in your response.

Comment: Presumably you are ordering these as "shorter strings always come before longer strings.  Strings of the same length are ordered lexicographically."   Right?

Comment: Trusting that this is the case, count all the strings of shorter length than the one you care about.  Now count all the strings of the same length that precede yours lexicographically.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. This is pretty much the strategy I am currently using. However, I was wondering whether there was some mathematical trick to further cut down the required computations.

Comment: Well, not that I know of.  Note that the problem is (clearly) closely related to the question of sums of binomial coefficients, and there isn't a terribly useful way of computing those either.

Comment: A recursive approach is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651983/c-recursive-permutations-in-lexicographical-order

Comment: You should make clearer whether it's truly a lexicographical (or reverse lexicographic) ordering that you desire...

Comment: In fact, what you want is a coherent ordering of subsets of a set and a way to access easily to any of them: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19152884/5802041)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going into the answer, consider whether you really need such a computation: this seems fairly strange and may be due to a problem elsewhere. The answer I give can perhaps be simplified.

As for how to compute the answer, consider an array a = a_1 ... a_k of length k. Because you order by number of elements first, you need to compute the number of arrays of length strictly smaller then k. The answer is simply summing the number of arrays of length i, for i <k. For a given i, the number of such arrays is n choose i, that is, n!/(n-i)!/i!.

Secondly, you need to compute the rank within the arrays of length k. First, you add all arrays with first element smaller than a_1. This is the sum for 1<= v < a_1 of (n-v-1) choose (k-1), as
all the (k-1) elements after must be chosen bigger than v. Then you need to do the same for arrays with first element a_1 but with second element smaller than a_2 (but still bigger than a_1).

[EDIT] I forgot you also wanted the reverse. The idea is similar: first compute the length of the array by getting the biggest i of the first for loop that does not go over the desired value. Then repeat this process for the rank (pick the first value as the biggest that does not go over, repeat for the second, ...). Code Updated.

Thus, the final algorithm can be written as:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned choose(unsigned n, unsigned i)
{
  unsigned res=1;
  for(unsigned k=n; k>i; k--)
    res*= k;
  for(unsigned k=1; k<=n-i; k++)
    res/= k;
  return res;
}

unsigned position(vector<unsigned> a, unsigned n)
{
  unsigned from_smaller =0;
  for(unsigned i=1; i<a.size(); i++)
     from_smaller+= choose(n, i);
  
  unsigned rank=0;
  unsigned prev_val=0; 
  for(unsigned i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
  {
      for(unsigned v=prev_val+1; v< a[i]; v++)
        rank+= choose(n-v, a.size()-i-1);
      prev_val=a[i];
  }
  return from_smaller + rank+1;
}  

vector<unsigned> from_position(unsigned position, unsigned n)
{
  vector<unsigned> a;
  unsigned len=0;
  while(position>=choose(n, len))
  {
     position-= choose(n, len);
     len++;
  }
  unsigned prev_val=0; 
  for(unsigned i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
      unsigned elem=prev_val+1;
      while(position >=choose(n-elem, len-i-1))
      {
         position -=choose(n-elem, len-i-1);
         elem++;
      }
      prev_val=elem;
      a.push_back(elem);
  }
  return a;
}
```

And the code to verify

```
// C++ template to print vector container elements
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<T>& v)
{
    os << "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        os << v[i];
        if (i != v.size() - 1)
            os << ", ";
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}


int main()
{
   unsigned n=7;
   for(unsigned i=1; i<=n; i++)
   {
          vector<unsigned> a={i};
          unsigned pos = position(a, n);
          vector<unsigned> arr = from_position(pos, n);
          std::cout<< "a="<<a<< " pos is "<<pos<<" from position is "<< arr<<"\n";
   }
   
   for(unsigned i=1; i<=n; i++)
   {
      for(unsigned j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
      {
          vector<unsigned> a={i, j};
          unsigned pos = position(a, n);
          vector<unsigned> arr = from_position(pos, n);
          std::cout<< "a="<<a<< " pos is "<<pos<<" from position is "<< arr<<"\n";
      }
   }
   
   
   for(unsigned i=1; i<=n; i++)
   {
      for(unsigned j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
      {
        for(unsigned k=j+1; k<=n ;k++)
        {
          vector<unsigned> a={i, j, k};
          unsigned pos = position(a, n);
          vector<unsigned> arr = from_position(pos, n);
          std::cout<< "a="<<a<< " pos is "<<pos<<" from position is "<< arr<<"\n";
        }
      }
   }
   
   for(unsigned i=1; i<=n; i++)
   {
      for(unsigned j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
      {
        for(unsigned k=j+1; k<=n ;k++)
        {
          for(unsigned l=k+1; l<=n ;l++)
          {
            vector<unsigned> a={i, j, k, l};
            unsigned pos = position(a, n);
            vector<unsigned> arr = from_position(pos, n);
            std::cout<< "a="<<a<< " pos is "<<pos<<" from position is "<< arr<<"\n";
          }
        }
      }
   }
     
   
}
```

PS: I am unable to get C++ syntax highlighting to work... The line I use is (without the " ")

> "```c++"

Comment: Thanks. I just tested it and love how fast it is.